# How do i get event.getEventById('id') or event.getEventSeriesById('id') to return anything other than null

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way to make the .getEventById or .getEventSereiesById return anyhting other than null? I get valid ID for the initial event creation and can make that into a full functional URL but cannot use it in its native environment for its native purpose.

I am trying to make a basic google sheets schedule system that can refer to the calendar invite to check for changes and update the sheet or vise versa based on which side is further out in time. The system will be used in an environment where the scheduling has multiple users and meetings can be moved around a lot, generally further out in time. Everything works right up until i try to get information from the calendar even, .getStartTime(), due to the .getEvent calls returning null. not sure how to fix what other sources are telling me is a nonfunctional command that yet still "functions as intended".

```
function IEPscheduler() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); // call sheet
    //var calendarID = spreadsheet.getRange("H1").getValue();
    var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("mascharterschool.com_0edapns33khde9ig0di31i2mvc@group.calendar.google.com");
    var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("A2:C2").getValues();
    var lr = spreadsheet.getLastRow();
    var lc = spreadsheet.getLastColumn(); //
    var count = spreadsheet.getRange(2,1,lr-1,lc-1).getValues();// get meeting data

    for (x=0; x<count.length; x++){
        var shift = count[x]; // pull row from meeting data
        var Start = shift[0];
        var End = shift[1];
        var Student = shift[2];
        var guests = shift[3];
        var description = shift[4];
        var location = shift[5];
        var run=shift[6]; // run following based on status column
        // new meeting is scheduled
        if(run == null || run == ''){
            var event = {
                'location': location,
                'description':description ,
                'guests':guests +',',
                'sendInvites': 'True',
                }
            var invite = eventCal.createEvent(Student, Start, End, event);
            invite.setGuestsCanInviteOthers(true);  // allow guests to invite others
            var eventId = invite.getId();
            var date = invite.getDateCreated();
            spreadsheet.getRange(x+2,7).setValue('Invite created'); // set status in sheet
            spreadsheet.getRange(x+2,8).setValue(date);     // inital date for created meeting invite
            spreadsheet.getRange(x+2,9).setValue(eventId);
        }
        // check existing meetings for updates
        else {
            var id = shift[9];
            var invite = eventCal.getEventSeriesById('id');
            // if the time or location has changed update calander
            if(invite.getStartTime() !== Start || invite.getEndTime() !== End || invite.getLocation() !== location){
                // if sheet override flagged
                if(shift[lc-1] !== null || Shift[lc-1] !== ''){
                    invite.setTime(Start,End); // update start/end time
                    invite.setLocation(location); // update location
                }
                // if canalder invite is further out than spreadsheet --> update spreadsheet
                if(invite.getStartTime() >> Start){ 
                    spreadsheet.getRange(x+2,1).setValue();
                    spreadsheet.getRange(x+2,2).setValue();
                }
                // if spread sheet time is later than invite --> updater invite
                else{
                    invite.setTime(Start,End); // update start/end time
                    invite.setLocation(location); // update location
                }
                var date = invite.getLastUpdate();
                spreadsheet.getRange(x+2,7).setValue('Updated'); // set new status in sheet
                spreadsheet.getRange(x+2,8).setValue(date); // set date meeting was updated
            }
            // if guest list has changed ???
            if 
        }
    }
}
// set script to be runnable from sheet tool bar
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Sync to Calendar') // tool bar banner
      .addItem('Create Events Now', 'IEPscheduler') // sub catageory (title, function to run)
      .addToUi();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We actually figured it out shortly after posting and I couldn't get back to this. Turns out the ID from .getId is the iCalUID and the .getEventById() takes a iCalID. The difference is that the UID has '@google.com' appended to the end of the ID. Split at the '@' and the get event works perfectly.

It's a stupid quirk that the getId command returns the right data in a useless form that requires editing to be used for its intended purpose.

Answer (score 0):

No nulls returned for me with this script:

```
function getEvents() {
  const cal=CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  const dt=new Date();
  const start=new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth()-1,dt.getDate());
  const end=new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate());
  var events=cal.getEvents(start, end);
  let eObj={idA:[],tA:[]}
  events.forEach(function(ev,i){
    eObj.idA.push(ev.getId());
    eObj.tA.push(cal.getEventById(ev.getId()).getTitle());
  });
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(eObj));
  return eObj;
}
```